How do I execute each SQL query in sequence and if 1 errors out then it continues?
I have my code here:
import os 
import json
import platform
import pymysql as pm
from datetime import date
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import logger
import requests
import boto3
import json, logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

class LogOutput:
    env=None
    config=None

    def __init__(self, env_filename):
        self.env=env_filename
        self.config=self.get_config()
        

    def get_config(self):
        with open(self.env) as file_in:
            return json.load(file_in)
        
    def is_Windows():
        if "win" in (platform.system().lower()):
            return True
        else:
            return False       

    def setup_logger():
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        
        # Rotating log setup
        log_filename = f"E:\\file\\Logs\\log-{date.today()}.log"
        file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_filename, when="midnight", backupCount=7)
        file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
        
        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
        
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        logger.addHandler(console_handler)
        return logger 
    setup_logger()

    def DB_connection(self):
        connection = None
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        try:
            config = self.get_config()
            host=config["log-output"]["database-secrets"]["host"]
            port=config["log-output"]["database-secrets"]["port"]
            database=config["log-output"]["database-secrets"]["db"]
            username=config["log-output"]["database-secrets"]["username"]
            password=config["log-output"]["database-secrets"]["password"]

            # Load the configuration from DB_conn_info_local.json
            config_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'DB_conn_info_local.json')
            with open(config_file_path) as config_file:
                config = json.load(config_file)

            connection = pm.connect(user=username,password=password,host=host,port=port,database=database)
    
            logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

        except Exception as e:
            logging.info("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))
        
        return connection
    
    
    def logging_sp(self):
        Query_1 = """
        select query 1

        Commit;
        """

        Query_2 = """
        select query 2

        Commit;
        """

        Query_3 = """

        select query 3

        commit;
        """

        Query_4 = """
        /*List of transactions to update. */

        select query 3
        commit;
        """

        Query_5 = """

        select query 5
        """
        cnxn = self.DB_connection()
        #query_list = ['Query_1', 'Query_2', 'Query_3', 'Query_4', 'Query_5']
        if cnxn is None:
            logging.error("Database connection is None. Cannot proceed.")
            return  # Exit here if there's no valid connection   
        try:   
            with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute(Query_1)
                cur.execute(Query_2)
                cur.execute(Query_3)
                cur.execute(Query_4)
                cur.execute(Query_5)
        except pm.err.Error as e:
            logging.error("Error: %s", e)
            apikey=self.get_secret()
            self.send_opsgenie_alert(apikey)
        else:
            print("Query_1 ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
            print("Query_2 ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
            print("Query_3 ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
            print("Query_4 ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
            print("Query_5 ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
            cnxn.commit()
            cnxn.close()  # Close the connection


def main():
    cwd=os.getcwd()
    if "win" in (platform.system().lower()):
        vfc=(cwd+"\\DB_conn_info_local"+".json")
    else:
        vfc=(cwd+"/DB_conn_info_local"+".json")
    ve=LogOutput(vfc)
    ve.logging_sp()
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Right now it is set up to execute all the queries right after each other, but if 1 errors out then the rest of them don't execute. I want to run them one after another. I have created a dictionary I commented out because I think that's what I have to use and also use a forloop with that possibly? So it goes through each query and then executes it and then goes onto the next even if the first fails...
EDIT
I removed the forloop and have my code like this now, i think its working and producing the correct row counts for each query:
cnxn = self.DB_connection()
if cnxn is None:
    logging.error("Database connection is None. Cannot proceed.")
    return  # Exit here if there's no valid connection   
with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
    try:
        cur.execute(Query_1)
        print(f'Query_1 ran successfully, {cur.rowcount} records updated')
    except pm.err.Error as e:
        logging.error("Error: %s", e)
        apikey=self.get_secret()
        self.send_opsgenie_alert(apikey)
    try:
        cur.execute(Query_2)
        print(f'Query_2 ran successfully, {cur.rowcount} records updated')
    except pm.err.Error as e:
        logging.error("Error: %s", e)
        apikey=self.get_secret()
        self.send_opsgenie_alert(apikey)
    try:
        cur.execute(Query_3)
        print(f'Query_3 ran successfully, {cur.rowcount} records updated')
    except pm.err.Error as e:
        logging.error("Error: %s", e)
        apikey=self.get_secret()
        self.send_opsgenie_alert(apikey)
    try:
        cur.execute(Query_4)
        print(f'Query_4 ran successfully, {cur.rowcount} records updated')
    except pm.err.Error as e:
        logging.error("Error: %s", e)
        apikey=self.get_secret()
        self.send_opsgenie_alert(apikey)
    try:
        cur.execute(Query_5)
        print(f'Query_5 ran successfully, {cur.rowcount} records updated')
    except pm.err.Error as e:
        logging.error("Error: %s", e)
        apikey=self.get_secret()
        self.send_opsgenie_alert(apikey)
    cnxn.commit()
    cnxn.close()  # Close the connection


You need to put each query in its own try/except, instead of wrapping it around all of them. The easiest way to do this is to put them in a list and loop through the list.
with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
for i, query in enumerate([Query_1, Query_2, Query_3, Query_4, Query_5], 1):
    try:
        cur.execute(query)
        print(f'Query #{i} ran successfully, {cur.rowcount} records updated')
    except pm.err.Error as e:
        logging.error(f"Error in query {i}, skipping: {e}")
        apikey=self.get_secret()
        self.send_opsgenie_alert(apikey)
cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()

Your code also reports the wrong number of records updated, since all the prints use the row count from the last query.

do i need cnxn.commit() after each try-except ? and just 1 cnxn.close() at the end? its running through each query 5 times

It's a little more efficient to do one commit at the end. And one commit means that everything will be atomic, other processes won't see partial updates.

ok thanks. i updated my post with the code without the forloop

If you have your own solution you should put that in an answer, not the question.

All that repetitive code is a violation of DRY principles. If you don't want a loop, put the common code in a function that you call.
